# IF row(NEW.*) IS DISTINCT FROM row(OLD.*) in postgresql how it works

Tags: sql, postgresql, distinct

How this code works. Is the NEW.* and OLD.* redundant.
Why don't just NEW.created_at <> OLD.created

```
  -- always reset the timestamp to the old value ("actual creation time")
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION before_update_users()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
  -- always reset the timestamp to the old value ("actual creation time")
  IF row(NEW.*) IS DISTINCT FROM row(OLD.*) THEN
      NEW.created_at := OLD.created_at;
      NEW.updated_at = now();
      RETURN NEW;
   ELSE
      RETURN OLD;
   END IF;
END;
$BODY$
```

Thanks

Comment: `row(NEW.*)` and ``row(OLD.*)` are redundant per [plpgsql trigger](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/plpgsql-trigger.html#PLPGSQL-DML-TRIGGER): *NEW Data type RECORD; variable holding the new database row for INSERT/UPDATE operations in row-level triggers.  ...*.

Answer (score 1):

Even if this trigger function is triggered by UPDATE it doesn't mean changes where actually made to the row.  row(NEW.*) IS DISTINCT FROM row(OLD.*) is used to detect if any values in the NEW row is actually distinct from any value in the OLD row.  If so - the updated_at is updated to current time to register the time of update.  The created_at remains the same and is therefore passed to the NEW row.

NEW.created_at <> OLD.created_at only compares one column in the NEW version and OLD version of the row and is useless when comparing the row as whole.  Furthermore if either value (or both) is null the expression will never evaluate to true.  Is distinct treats null as actual values and compares accordingly.

You can find more information on row comparing here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-comparisons.html#ROW-WISE-COMPARISON